# ng-repeat with different element types

Tags: html, angularjs, svg

Is it possible to add different HTML elements types in an `ng-repeat`?

If I have an array:

```
['line', 'arc', 'rectangle', 'line', 'polygon', ... ]
```

These elements will have different SVG tags and different data to define them.

Is it possible to have AngularJS insert the correct tag based on the value?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest making a `directive` that will get past in the scope of the repeater and the do an `element.replaceWith` and a `$compile` to get the HTML. if there is no further binding of angular, you could just use `$sce` to output trusted HTML. Prob depends on the type of security needed on the site, I'd go with the directive personally.
** I HAVE NOT TESTED BELOW and I dont know anything about canvas/svg stuff :-)

html on page

```
    <svg-object varObject="o" data-ng-repeat="o in varObjects"></svg-object>
```

json model on controller

```
$scope.varObjects = [{ "shape": "circle", "id": "cir123", "cx": "50", "cy": "50", "r": "50", "fill": "red" }, { "shape": "rect", "id": "rec23", "width": "50", "height": "50", "fill": "green" }]
```

Declare your module, name it and include the named module in your app

```
var module = angular.module('myApp.directives', [])
module.directive('svgObject', function ($compile) {
return {
    scope:{ varObject:'@'
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

        var rsltHtml = '<' + scope.varObject.shape
        for (var property in scope.varObject) {
            switch (property) { //properties to ignore
                case "shape":
                case "alsoignore":
                    continue;
            }
            if (scope.varObject.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                rsltHtml += ' '+ property + '="' + scope.varObject[property]+ '" ';
            }
        }
        rsltHtml += "/>";
        elem.replaceWith($compile(rsltHtml)(scope));
    }
};
```

});

add directive to main app

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.directives', 'ngSanitize'])
```

Comment: Cool, that's allot of things I don't know about.  I'll hit the books, any elaboration on how I go about doing those things would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I do this using a ng-repeat with the elements in the array, and then do a ng-switch on the value.

```
<li ng-repeat="q in context.array">
    <div ng-switch on="q.type">
       <div ng-switch-when="line">I AM A LINE</div>
       <div ng-switch-when="arc">I AM AN ARC</div>
       <div ng-switch-when="rectangle">I AM A RECTANGLE</div>
       <div ng-switch-when="polygon">I AM A POLYGON</div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about the run time implications of this but using ng-switch is just showing/hiding the DOM elements as opposed to actually fetching the parts dynamically, correct?  So far I've stuck with the directive method myself and switching out the template (loading it from cache if possible otherwise fetching it as needed).  I do like the simplicity of this approach though and wonder if my paranoia about performance is warranted, does this work well in complex apps on mobile devices?

Comment: I am not using this on mobile, so I cant speak to that. I am sure that you could come up with other solutions. This is one that I use and haven't seen any issues with, however my repeat is limited to ~2 - 20 elements.

Comment: I'm going to give this a try, but I think the `<div />` will be an issue, even if the show\hide isn't.  I'll report back what happens.

Comment: Looks like it works, see this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BanksySan/UHNDU). Angular actually comments out the unused elements, which makes for a lot of letters in the compiled file, but not a massive DOM!